# 2004 ford f150 smoke coming out of my two back tires

Tags: brakes, tires, brake-rotor, vibration, smoke

I was driving into town the other day , I noticed vibration on the truck . At first i thought it was just the road . Later I felt like some body comes behind me and gives me a little push on the truck while I was driving . When that happened the engine light turned on for a little bit . When I got to my place I noticed smoke coming out of my 2 back tires , it smelled really bad (burning rubber) . 
Could it be a cylinder , caliper ?
I just put a new caliper on 2 weeks ago , and also new wheels bearings on both sides . What could cause all of that to happen

Answer (score 1):

@Pete: I was thinking that as a possibility as well. If the bearings were over tightened they would self destruct within an hour and would be a catastrophic failure. I had that on 1989 VW Fox destroyed the race, pulverized the bearings and with such force it the retaining nut milled the spindle smooth as the drum impacted the spindle. This happened on both rear wheels.

I doubt it would be the calipers seeing that they were new. One possible explanation for the vibration  and the smoke from the tires as well a light on the dash board. Were the parking brakes not fully released?

Comment: Parking brakes were my thinking as well.

Comment: @paulster2- Great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it sounds like the wheel bearings weren't installed correctly - too tightly or too loosely - that could account for the 'little push', as the bearings seize and then release. The smoke could be the bearing grease burning off (I've seen more than once - and done it once - where Lithium Grease was used on a wheel bearing. It burns off very quickly, and the bearing dies within weeks. You need to use high-temperature grease specifically designed for wheel bearings).